# Convergence of ratio between two sequenses

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that 
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Does the following sum converges or diverges ?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^2}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $a_n$ such that $\frac{a_n}n=\frac 1{\log n}$. The corresponding series is divergent (it's $\sum_n\frac 1{n\log n}$).